# how to made one-to-one bidirectional relationships in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have two domain classes and want to have one-to-one BIDIRECTIONAL relation between them. I write:

```
class Person {

  Book book;

  String name
  Integer age
  Date lastVisit

  static constraints = {
    book unique: true  // "one-to-one". Without that = "Many-to-one".
  }

}
```

```
class Book {

  String title
  Date releaseDate
  String ISBN

  static belongsTo = [person:Person] // it makes relationship bi-directional regarding the grails-docs 
}
```

So, i want to have bi-directional, i could NOT find link from Book to Person in generated SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `release_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

So then it means it is not bidirectional then? How to make bidirectional?

Comment: Write a test that queries your books and see if person is available.  Bidirectional doesn't mean what you think, in this case. It simply means, can you access person from book.

Answer (score 3):

check out the hasOne property, in which class you define hasOne and belongsTo depends on where you want the FK to be stored, check this grails doc regarding hasOne:
http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html

Answer (score 1):

To make this relationship one to one bidirectional,you should define them as fallows

```
     //Person is the owning side of relationship
     class Person {

      //a foreign key will be stored in Book table called person_id
      static hasOne = [book:Book]

      static constraints = {
        book unique: true
      }  
    }

    Class Book{
     Person person
    }
```

belongsTo is used for specifying the owner side(which manages relationship) of a one-to-many, many-to-one, or many-to-many relationship and for making relationship bidirectional

belongsTo should be used always in owned side